# Determine a width percentage value on a progress-bar

Tags: javascript, progress-bar

My Animated GIF Image Player Library in JavaScript is going to have a progressbar similar to the one in the image below shown when the play and pause buttons are clicked.

For an example if my GIF animation has 5 Frames with these time duration values:

#### GIF Animation Frames with Duration Times:

- Frame 1 = 3,000ms
- Frame 2 = 3,000ms
- Frame 3 = 5,000ms
- Frame 4 = 22,000ms
- Frame 5 = 1,000ms

In the above example the total GIF animation duration time would be **34,000ms**

---

Using JavaScript I need to determine what percent each frame takes up on the Progressbar I am building.

When a JS function set the active GIF Frame to be frame #3 above, it should highlight my progressbar to the width thatframes 1 and 2 consumeso that the starting position on progressbar is the start of frame 3.

So it would take 6,000ms from frame 1 + frame 2 andget the percentage from the GIF total time of 34,000ms and transform that into a percentage width on the DOM element

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
34000/100 = 340;

3000/340 = 8.823529411764707;

(3000 + 3000)/340 = 17.647058823529413;

(3000 + 3000 + 5000)/340 = 32.35294117647059;

(3000 + 3000 + 5000 + 22000)/340 = 97.05882352941177;

(3000 + 3000 + 5000 + 22000 + 1000)/340 = 100;
```

Comment: The far right value is the percent of time for that frame on the total duration or the percent of width on the progressbar using the time percent?  Also what does the 340 represent?

Comment: @JasonDavis Yes. `340` is total possible duration divided by `100`. Divide accrued values by `340` to derive percentage in relation to `34000`.